# Make "move item" a default right click option

Tags: finder

Is it possible to get the option (⌥) + right click move item here command to show up by default on right click when copy pasting items between different locations in finder. Rather than having to hold the option key ?

Im using OSX 10.10

Comment: I'm not sure what feature you are talking about. Could be just me, but I'm kinda lost. I'm using 10.11 right now and `⌥ + right click (or drag)` is not a thing I can do and neither is `⌥ + left click`. `⌥ + left drag` is, but it copies a file wherever you drag it and you started the question talking about "moving"... though then later you used the term "copy pasting" so..? `Right clicking` a file and then holding `⌥` while the context menu is open does reveal hidden options as is the case with many osx menus, but it doesn't reveal any move options either. — Care to clarify this a bit?

Comment: @Joonas - you're more likely to see it if you use Icon View, as you need to hit some empty space. It's not really something I'd ever need in the right-click menu, as I find it a whole lot easier to just Cmd/C Cmd/opt/V

Comment: @Tetsujin, riiiiiight. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Sam, I don't think it's possible without a third party app. As mentioned by @Tetsujin, there is a native shortcut for moving a file `Cmd+C` and `Cmd+Alt+V`, but if you don't wish to use shortcuts, you may have to use a third party app.

<sup><sub>I guess you could make an Automator Service, but you'd have to access it from the  "Services" submenu thing and I feel it would be more of a hindrance than a real solution.</sub></sup>

**3rd party applications that add "Cut" to the context menu:**

All of these applications use the same logic as Windows, when it comes to moving files this way, which is to say backwards from how it works in macs: You start with the intent to "Copy" or "Cut" file(s) and then just normally "Paste" to complete the action. Cutting = Moving.

<sup><sub>Should be noted that from 10.11. onward XtraFinder and TotalFinder become more difficult to run, as they need to inject code to Finder and [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) is not into that. I believe both support disabling SIP → installing → enabling SIP. I know TotalFinder does.</sub></sup>

- [XtraFinder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) - Free app.

  - Adds "Cut" to the context menu.
  - `XtraFinder Preferences > Features > Cut & Paste`
- [TotalFinder](https://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) - Paid app.

  - Adds "Cut" to the context menu. It's on by default.

    - There's an alternative `Finder Preferences > TotalFinder > Menus > Show CutPaste buttons in Context Menus`, which turns `Cut` `Copy` `Paste` into buttons all in one line in the context menu.
  - Though I'd highly advice against it, you can disable the tabs if that is not your thing.
  - More or less the same as XtraFinder with some differences.
- [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com/) - Paid app.

  - `Path Finder Preferences > Features > Contextual Menu`.

    - Commands list on the left contains all possible context menu items, `Cut` being one of them and the Contextual Menu list on the right contains all the current items in the context menu. You should be aware that these are contextual... Like for example, you won't see "Copy Dropbox Link" in the actual context menu if the file is not in your Dropbox folder.
  - Finder replacement. The other two apps extend Finder functionality.
  - Has a fully customizable context menu.
  - In general is more customizable than the other two.
  - Should be noted that many things that irritate people when they first start using Path Finder can be changed from the `View > Show View Options`. Some of them being "Bold folders" and "Smart Sorting".

All of these application have shortcuts too:

- `Cmd+C` = Copy
- `Cmd+X` = Cut
- `Cmd+V` = Paste

Path Finder and XtraFinder both have `Move to...` and `Copy to...` context menu items as well.